# How to set MKMapview default language to English?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on multiple language based app in which I have used MKMapview(Map). When I set device language 'Korean', MKMapview(Map) language changed to 'Korean'. But I want Map language in 'English'. Is anyone know how to achieve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible, you can only use `googlesdk` instead.

Comment: Ok.Is there any way to get selected location in 'English' in response?